# How to retrieve Data by ID - angular

Tags: html, angular, json-server

ANGULAR & JSON SERVER

I have done Post Mapping and the inserted values are getting posted inside my db.json file. I need to retrieve data when fetched by ID. I have created a form field to search with ID. In the below code what I have to give instead of myData since I need to fetch from the db.json/getOne().

**My service file:**

getOne(id)
{
return this.http.get("http://localhost:3000/posts/"+ id).pipe(map((res)=>{
return res
}))
}

**component.ts file:**

getDataText(id)
{
const data = myData.find(x => x.id === id);
return data ? data.text : `Cannot find data with id ${id}`;
}

**html file snippet**:

<button [disabled]="!idForm.valid" class="btn btn-primary mt-3" (click)="getDataText(id)">Get Details

Comment: Did you inject the service in the component having myData?

Comment: Yes. I have given like this in my compo.ts:- constructor(private service : MyService){}

Comment: Then you can access the myData from the service that returns the observable from the API.
```this.service.getOne(example_id).subscribe(myData => {console.log(myData);)```

You should be able to access the myData this way.
I hope this what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: pro tip: you can use code fences to format the code